# How to easily find an Ice Plains Spikes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been looking for an Ice Plains Spikes, but I seem to be able to find nothing. I want to build an Eskimo village there, but I can't find any at all. I've looked around cold biomes, but nothing. Any easy way to find one?

I am using 1.7.2 SMP.

Comment: Try: http://chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder and enter your seed. It is almost 100% accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Finding an ice biome is a rare event so there is no "easy" way of finding one, unless you find a seed which spawns you in that biome.

Alternatively, you can use [AMIDST](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v36-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder-174/) to find a biome you are looking for within an existing world, so you are not walking around aimlessly.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy to finding any sort of biome is to search for biomes of similar climate.  If you're looking for ice spikes, (which happens to be one of the rarest) you should look for tundras, cold taigas, and the like.